# DotNetOpenAuth Simple Demo, MVC & Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth, membership

I've been looking around some time for a very simple implementation using DotNetOpenAuth to allow users to log into my application using their Google account, Yahoo account, or other OpenId.  I've done some digging and searching through DotNetOpenAuth's website as well as checked out some other projects' source code which utilizes this service but none of them seem to be very straight-forward at all. (Including the samples from DotNetOpenAuth's site.)

Does anyone have a link to a tutorial/demo/example which would demonstrate most of the following?

1. Allow a user to sign in using Google, Yahoo, other OpenId, OR the "regular" ASP.NET membership account. (Very similar to the NerdDinner demo)
2. Upon initial sign-in, capture information like FirstName, LastName, E-MailAddress, etc from external source (e.g. Google).
3. If the user is logging in for the first time, save that membership information mentioned above (probably into the ASP.NET Membership tables).
4. Upon subsequent log-ins, retrieve that user's record from the ASP.NET Membership tables.
5. Using MVC 3 with the Razor engine.

Any assistance you could provide would be appreciated.  Chances are, the information I need I've already seen in some of these other demos.  I just do not have the information about exactly what the code is doing to fully wrap my head around the functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how to make it more clear than [this](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Creating-an-openid-relying-party-%28programatically%29#mvc).  And if you like the NerdDinner sample, it's available as open source as well, so check out what they do.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew.  This mixed with the information I found here http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx helped me put it all together.  Thanks for the guidance.